# Parse HTML stored as string in Database in ColdFusion

Tags: parsing, coldfusion, wddx

I have taken over this ColdFusion project and found that I need a value out of a database field that includes HTML. The field data looks like this (without the new lines):

```
<wddxPacket version="1.0">
    <header />
    <data>
        <struct>
            <var name="en">
                <string>3 Nights' Lodging</string>
            </var>
            <var name="sp">
                <string>3 Noches alojamiento</string>
            </var>
        </struct>
    </data>
</wddxPacket>
```

I am wanting to use this data but I only need the text between the:

`<var name='en'><string>3 Nights' Lodging</string></var>`

I used a function that ColdFusion has to remove HTML:

```
#REReplaceNoCase(pkg.title, "<[^><]*>", '', 'ALL')#
```

But when I use that, I get something like this:

```
3 Nights' Lodging3 Noches alojamiento
```

All I want is:

```
3 Nights' Lodging
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Examining the beginning of the string, ie `<wddxPacket ...>` it is actually [WDDX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WDDX).

If you do a search for ColdFusion + WDDX you will find the documentation for [CFWDDX](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/using-web-elements-and-external-objects/using-xml-and-wddx/using-wddx.html). It is a built in tag which supports conversions of WDDX strings to CFML objects (and vice versa) for easier manipulation. In your case use `action="wddx2cfml"` to convert the string back into a CF structure.

```
<cfwddx action="wddx2cfml" input="#text#" output="result">
<cfdump var="#result#" label="Raw object">
```

Then use the key `#result.en#` to grab the string you want.